# Find all possible linear systems with defined solution set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all possible linear systems with solution set being a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ produced by vectors (1,6,6),(1,1,1),(6,5,5). My knowledge of linear algebra is rusty, and I need to deal with this problem. Any ideas? Thank you .

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you for example noticed that may be $u,v,w$ are not independant ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I have. Also I have found out that the matrix formed by those 3 vectors has Rank=2. Also I did some calculations and manage to completely reduce the matrix to (1,0,0),(0,1,1),(0,0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u=(1,6,6)^T,v=(1,1,1)^T,w=(6,5,5)^T$ are dependant (two last rows of matrix $[u,v,w]$ are identical, proving that their determinant is zero).

It suffices then to work with $u=(1,6,6)$ and $v=(1,1,1)$, which are independent.

Let $t=u \times v$ their cross product, with components 
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 5 \\ -5 
\end{pmatrix}.$

The 2-dimensional set $E$ of all the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z 
\end{pmatrix}$ of the form $au+bv$ can be characterized by the fact that all $au+bv$ are orthogonal to $w$.

$E$ can then be described as the solution of the following "system with a single equation":

$0x+5y-5z=0$, or in a simpler way $y=z$...

Comment: I had come to some similar conclusions , but this is very nicely written. Thank you very much .